# Storing activities to be opened to objects

Tags: android

I am storing an intent in shared preferences like so :

```
new Intent(context, MainActivity.this);
```

and then when I try to open it I am getting the error :

```
  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {  }
```

I assume it's because `context` is referring to the stored activity? when `context` should be the current activity.

My question is how do I get around this one? I have several buttons which is populated by objects stored in the preferences. Each of them opens different activities. Basically I am mapping activities to be opened to buttons.

To give you an idea :

```
public class Scene implements Serializable {
    public String label;
    public Intent intent;
    public boolean isUnlocked;

    public Scene(String lbl, Intent i) {
        this.label = lbl;
        this.intent = i;
    }
}

for (Scene scene : savedScenesFromSharedPreferences) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()) {
       startActivity(scene.intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with that

Comment: Do not persist an `Intent`. Persist some sort of stable identifier, such as an integer. Then, at runtime, decide how to handle a scene with that identifier. Right now, your solution is very brittle. It will not handle change well such as deciding to rename your activities, move your activities to another Java package, needing extras on the `Intent`, changing to using fragments, changing to using the Navigation component, changing to using Jetpack Compose, etc. Your data storage format should be independent of how you GUI is assembled; your current approach ties those two tightly together.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need only load the scene (ie. the activity). I do not need those. I guess I have to hard code everything then.

Comment: "I need only load the scene (ie. the activity)" -- that is how you are loading the scene *today*. Your plans may change in the future, but your file format for existing files on user devices will not. For example, you are already using an out-of-date development technique (one activity per screen) compared to Google's current recommendations (one fragment per screen), let alone when compared to Google's long-term direction (one composable per screen). If you wish for your app to have long-term use, design your file format to be adaptable to change.

Comment: The scenes are levels of the game. I have an activity for each level. Why I save the scenes is because they have different states (ie isUnlocked). Maybe I could store the intents in a variable instead? and then store the state in the preference and map them to each scene upon loading.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

In your Scene class, instead of saving the Intent, save the activity name.

```
scene.setLabel("Button A");
scene.setActivityName("com.example...YourOtherActivityName");
```

To start the activity:

```
    startActivity(new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, Class.forName(scene.getActivityName)));
```